# Стандартный шаблон в Djnago-cms

Tags: python, cms, django

Добрый день. Как в django-cms поставить шаблон? Такой, как тут [https://django-cms.org/](http://django-cms.org/).
Как я понимаю, он есть в самом пакете cms?

Comment: джанго не cms

Comment: но при этом django-cms это cms

Answer (score 1):

В пакете `Django-CMS` нет набора стандартных шаблонов - все нужно писать самому. Посмотрите в папку `templates/cms` в пакете с этой CMS - там находится, помимо прочего, шаблон `new.html`, дефолтная страница только что поднятой CMS. Больше - ничего интересного.

С другой стороны, поищите по запросу `django-cms themes`. Я, например, нашел [этот сайт](http://www.djangocmsthemes.com/themes/).